# Microsoft Teams: Visual Studio Connector

Tags: microsoft-teams

I installed free desktop version of Teams(1.1.00.18052, 64-bit), but while adding connector, I cant see Visual Studio and Team Services connector. Is it not available in free version?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's an authentication bug with the free version of Teams, so it's temporarily disabled. Once the VSTS team fixes it we'll enable it. I don't have an ETA but it should be fairly quick based on other apps that have had the same problem.

Comment: Does anyone know when this will be available again. Kind of embarrassing for MS to not get this working. I wanted to switch from Slack to Teams but if these things do not work, I'm not sure I want to...